# If $a_0<\dots<a_n<b_n<\dots<b_0$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$ then $\sup( a_n)\le\inf(b_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, examples-counterexamples, supremum-and-infimum

Let be $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and increasing and a decreasing sequence of reals numbers such that
$$
a_0<\dots <a_n<b_n<\dots<b_0
$$
for any $n\in\Bbb N$. So by the last inequality it is evident that $b_0$ is an upper bound for $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $a_0$ is a lower bound for $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ so that we can claim that $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ has a supremum $M$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ has a infimum $m$ but unfortunately I was not able to prove or disprove if $M\le m$ so that I thought to put here a specific question where I ask to prove or disporve it with a counterexample.

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: **Hint :** For every $k$ and $n$, you have $a_k < b_n$. Show that this implies that for every $n$, $M \leq b_n$, and deduce that this implies that $M \leq m$.

Comment: So if $M\le b_n$ then $M$ would be a lower bound for $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ so that clearly it would be $M\le m$, right? However I do not see why it must be $M\le b_n$, could you explain it, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: Just fix $n$. You have that for every $k$, $a_k < b_n$. So isn't $b_n$ an upper bound for the sequence $(a_k)$ ? What can you deduce from that ?

Comment: Sorry, if $a_k<b_k$ for any $k\in\Bbb N$ then why $a_k<b_n$ for an arbitrary $n$? Indeed is it impossible that $a_5<b_5$ but $b_7<a_5$? I am a bit confused.

Comment: You are right, but look closely at your hypothesis $a_0 < ... < a_n < b_n < ... < b_0$. Don't you see that it implies that $a_k < b_n$ for every $k$ and $n$ ?

Comment: Oh yeah! So if $b_n<a_m$ for any $m,n\in\Bbb N$ then $b_n<a_m<b_m$ so that $n> m$ because $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is decreasing; however the hypotesis implies that $a_n<b_n<a_m$ so that it would be $n<m$ and this is impossible if $n>m$, right?

Comment: Yes, or more simply you can say that for every $n$ and $m$, one has $$a_m \leq a_{n+m} < b_{n+m} < b_n$$

Comment: Oh yeah!!! So thanks very much for your hint! Obviously if you will write an answer I will surely accept it.

Comment: Your question is (to some extent) similar to this one: [Prove that $\sup S \leq \inf T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3508153)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes it is surely similar but I think that it is different because I ask to prove that $a_n<b_m$ for any $m,n\in\Bbb N$ but effectively showed this the result follows immediately by the question you linked.

Comment: Looking at your older posts, it seems that this question was inspired by the response you got here: [Explanation about the following proof of uncountability of $\Bbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4400272).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Oh yeah! sure.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Could I ask to you if the proof I gave on the uncountability of $\Bbb R$ is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if there existed $h,k\in\Bbb N$ such that $b_k<a_h$ then these would be such that
$$
a_k<b_k<a_h<b_h
$$
So if $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is decreasing then the inequality $b_k<b_h$ implies that $k>h$ but if $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is increasing then the inequality $a_k<a_h$ implies that $k<h$ so that the inequality $b_k<a_h$ would imply that $k>h$ and $k<h$ but this is clearly impossible: so we conclude that
$$
a_h<b_k
$$
for any $h,k\in\Bbb N$ and this implies that $b_k$ is an upper bound for $(a_h)_{h\in\Bbb N}$ so that $M\le b_k$ but this means that $M$ is a lower bound for $(b_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ and so finally $M\le m$.

**OBSERVATION**

Alternatively as TheSilverDoe showed in the comments above the inequality $a_h<b_k$ can follow immediately observing that
$$
a_h<a_{h+k}<b_{h+k}<b_k
$$

Comment: Probably it is worth pointing out a bit problematic notation. The letter $m$ is sometimes used as a natural number (as an index) and at the same time you denoted $m=\inf\limits_{n\in\mathbb N} b_n$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak You are right, I am editing immediately the answer.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Answer edited. Do you see any others mistakes?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Oh, thanks for the edit! :)